# Not fetching correct url issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, model, underscore.js

I have a backboneJS app that has a router that looks

```
var StoreRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
   routes: {
     'stores/add/' : 'add',
     'stores/edit/:id': 'edit'
   },
   add: function(){
     var addStoresView = new AddStoresView({
       el: ".wrapper"
     });
   },
   edit: function(id){
       var editStoresView = new EditStoresView({
          el: ".wrapper",
          model: new Store({ id: id })
       });
   }
});
var storeRouter = new StoreRouter();
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, hashChange: false });
```

and a model that looks like:

```
var Store = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: "/stores/"
});
```

and then my view looks like:

```
var EditStoresView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
render: function() {

   this.model.fetch({
      success : function(model, response, options) {
          this.$el.append ( JST['tmpl/' + "edit"] (model.toJSON()) );
      }
   });
}
```

I thought that urlRoot when fetched would call **/stores/ID_HERE**, but right now it doesn't call that, it just calls **/stores/**, but I'm not sure why and how to fix this?

In devTools, here is the url it's going for:

```
GET http://localhost/stores/
```

Comment: You'll need to post a bit more of your source, setting the `urlRoot` might not be the issue.

Comment: @Whymarrh, Sure, what parts would be helpful? The rest of the view code?

Comment: @the_: The issue isn't in the code you gave here - I tried completing it and the URL is being generated correctly. Feel free to add `console.log(id)` to `StoreRouter.edit()`, maybe the `id` parameter simply isn't being set correctly. Alternatively, maybe there is some other code path in your application that is being taken instead of the one you copied here.

Comment: @WladimirPalant, Ok I did console.log(id); in the StoreRouter.edit(), but it just correctly returned the id?

Comment: @WladimirPalant, I just edited and added my only other route function.

Comment: @the_: Feel free to continue debugging - e.g. `console.log(this.model.get("id"))` and `console.log(this.model.url())` in `EditStoresView.render()`.

Comment: @the_: Is the model declaration completely demonstrated here? Because this issue could be achieved if you have changed `idAttribute` of `Backbone.Model`. By default it is 'id', but if you have changed it `this.model.url()` will not concat anything to your `rootUrl`.

Comment: @WladimirPalant, Ok this.model.url() returns `/stores/` and this.model.get("id") returns `undefined`

Comment: @VahanVardanyan, Yes, I only have the rootUrl in my model as posted, nothing else.

Comment: Can you share the code which initiates the routing of application url 'stores/edit/:id'. The issue might be there. For debugging purpose, you can try hardcoding a specific number in place of id i.e. `model: new Store({ id: 2 })`, this will help in locating the error.

Comment: @ManishMulimani, Can you clarify what you mean by the "initiates the routing" code? I'm not really sure which code you're referring to. I tried hardcoding the model id, but the url still keeps going to /stores/, so I think the error must be with the model somehow?

Comment: @the_: `console.log(new Store({ id: 2 }).get("id"))` gives me `2` (Backbone.js 1.1.2, Underscore.js 1.6.0), is it the same for you? So far it sounds like you are overwriting the model associated with the view somewhere.

Comment: @the_ Here's a Fiddle with what you gave http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/6QFcY/1/ and it works as is

Comment: So what was the problem in the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be the answer since it depends on your real production code.

Normally the code you entered is supposed to work, and I even saw a comment saying that it works in a jsfiddle. A couple of reasons might affect the outcome:

- In your code you changed the `Backbone.Model.url()` function. By default the url function is

  ```
  url: function() {
        var base =
          _.result(this, 'urlRoot') ||
          _.result(this.collection, 'url') ||
          urlError();
        if (this.isNew()) return base;
        return base.replace(/([^\/])$/, '$1/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
      },
  ```

  This is the function to be used by Backbone to generate the URL for `model.fetch();`.
- You added a custom `idAttribute` when you declared your Store Model to be like the one in your DB. For example your database has a different id than `id` itself, but in your code you still use `new Model({ id: id });` when you really should use `new Model({ customId: id });`. What happens behind the scenes is that you see in the `url()` function it checks if the model `isNew()`. This function actually checks if the `id` is set, but if it is custom it checks for that:

  ```
  isNew: function() {
        return !this.has(this.idAttribute);
      },
  ```
- You messed up with `Backbone.sync` ... lots of things can be done with this I will not even start unless I want to make a paper on it. Maybe you followed a tutorial without knowing that it might affect some other code.
- You called `model.fetch()` "a la" $.ajax style:

  ```
  model.fetch({
    data: objectHere,
    url: yourUrlHere,
    success: function () {},
    error: function () {}
  });
  ```

  This overrides the awesomeness of the Backbone automation. (I think sync takes over from here, don't quote me on that).

Reference: [Backbone annotated sourcecode](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html)